# How to get the relationship between two colors?

Tags: html, css, colors, sass

We use as our reference a style guide from User Experience team, which usually documents the colour palette in hexadecimal values.
For example:

```
Primary Color : #F27132;
Hover color : #D16605;
```

Based on these values we need to create our stylesheet(.scss file).
scss uses some functions like `$lighten`, `$darken`, `$saturate`, `$desaturate` etc.
Is there any way to convert these hex codes into such relative formats? Something like,

```
$primary-color : #F27132
$hower-color : $darken($primary-color, 20%)
```

Comment: I dont think you need any conversion tool for this. This is handled by SCSS already. Your code should work just fine

Comment: But provided that the Hower color povided is exactly 20% dark than the Primary color.

Comment: you could split the primary color to three hex values (F2, 71, 32), calculate the decimal values, reduce by 20% (darken), convert back to hex values and then you have your hower color.

Comment: Are you looking for [`from_hex`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Value/Color.html#from_hex-class_method)?

Comment: 20% is just an approximate figure I have given in an example.
I am looking out for a way to calculate the exact number. A tool which will give me if  the second color is x% darker or lighter than first color.

Comment: Ah, you want to do the inverse of darken, give a function two colors and get the brightness relationship? Then you should split the colors into hsl values and divide the two L values

Comment: What is the point of using color transforming functions if the User Experience team tells you exactly what color values to use?

Comment: Ya, that is what I am trying.
I got hsl values of two colors as hsl(20, 88%, 57%) and
hsl(29, 95%, 42%);
Now how to decide the percentage of lightness/darkness from that?

Comment: These cannot be the same colors with change in brightness.. H and S values suggests that they are different only L should change when you do the math of your percentage calculations

Comment: The Hue and saturation should not change if there's change in luminescence is what i meant. The colors provided here are two different colors

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and found no good answer, so I wrote the following code:

```scss
/// Get difference HSL values between two colors 
/// @param {Color} $color1 - Base color
/// @param {Color} $color2 - Second color to compare
/// @param {Bool} $rounded - If returned HSL values must be rounded,
///                          if yes final color will not be exactly the same
/// @return {Debug} - Difference of HSL values between two colors
@mixin getHslDifference( $color1, $color2, $rounded: false ) {
    /* Get HSL values of colors */
    $hue1: hue($color1);
    $sat1: saturation($color1);
    $lig1: lightness($color1);
    $hue2: hue($color2);
    $sat2: saturation($color2);
    $lig2: lightness($color2);

    /* Get hue difference */
    $hueDiff: -( math.div( $hue1, ( $hue2 * 0 + 1 ) )
        - math.div( $hue2, ( $hue1 * 0 + 1 ) ) ); // Strip units
    $hueDiff: if($rounded == true, round($hueDiff), $hueDiff);

    /* Get saturation difference */
    $satDiff: -( $sat1 - $sat2);
    $satDiff: if( $rounded == true, round($satDiff), $satDiff );

    /* Get lightness difference */
    $ligDiff: -( $lig1 - $lig2 );
    $ligDiff: if( $rounded == true, round($ligDiff), $ligDiff );

    @debug "Increase hue by " + $hueDiff;
    @debug "Increase saturation by " + $satDiff;
    @debug "Increase lightness by " + $ligDiff;
}

// 1 - Set the primary color value
$primary-color: #F27132;

// 2 - Get the relationship HSL values between primary and hover colors
@include getHslDifference( $primary-color, #D16605 );

// Will output:
// Debug: Increase hue by 8.8419117647
// Debug: Increase saturation by 7.2537083083%
// Debug: Increase lightness by -15.2941176471%


// 3 - Set the hover color value dynamically (now you can delete previous step
// hexadecimal value of hover color is no more needed)
$hover-color: hsl(
    hue($primary-color) + 8.8419117647,
    saturation($primary-color) + 7.2537083083%,
    lightness($primary-color) + -15.2941176471%
);

@debug $hover-color; // Debug: #d16605
```

Answer (score -2):

This works out-of-the-box with Sass. Watch out however that the dollar sign is used when declaring functions but not when using functions. Hence this will work :

```
$hower-color : darken($primary-color, 20%)
```

Comment: Question is about a way to calculate that number 20%.
In my question, I have given it just as an example.
What I want is, If I give 2 hex values, I need an output as,
2nd color is x% darker or lighter than 1st color.